Can't get chatbot working on both standard and custom domain
We have both standard and custom domain and for our QA team testing we wanted to maintain the chatbot on both domains.
However, when we add a custom domain to ESW site, chatbot works fine on the custom domain but doesn't work on the standard domain and vice versa, when we remove the custom domain from ESW site, chatbot works fine on the standard domain but stops working on the custom domain.
Is this possible to get the bot working on both domains?

Salesforce support replied to me that they are able to display the messaging button on the site, but it remains in a spinning state due to a known issue https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xAzaEAAS/~.
Troubleshooting documentation they provided:
[Troubleshoot Messaging for In-App and Web Setup, please refer Refused to load the script] - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.miaw_troubleshoot.htm&type=5
Another reference to the documentation they provided: [Considerations and Limitations for Messaging for In-App and Web] - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.miaw_considerations_and_limitations.htm&type=5
Overall: we shouldn't add a custom CDN domain to the ESW site.
